# Scikit-learn : roc_auc_score returns different values depending on whether the ground truth is one hot encoded

Tags: scikit-learn

Not sure what is going on, but:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
y_true = np.random.randint(np.ones((100,1))*5)
y_scores = RandomForestClassifier().fit(np.random.rand(100,5),y_true.ravel()).predict_proba(np.random.rand(100,5))
oh=OneHotEncoder()
print(roc_auc_score(oh.fit_transform(y_true.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray(), y_scores,multi_class='ovo'))
print(roc_auc_score(y_true.ravel(), y_scores,multi_class='ovo'))
```

keeps giving me different outputs (obviously I expect it to give different values everytime I run it, but I expect one hot encoded and non one hot encoded truth values to return the same thing. Sample output:

```
0.5141240772057938
0.5242429384699121
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong (just want to understand if I'm missing something).